# Copy row from one sheet to another base on cell value

Tags: javascript

My knowledge of java is very light. I've created that code form consulting 5, 6 code in here and the developers google group but can figure out the conditional thing.

Basically i want to copy a whole row that contain the word "AAF" or "SEQ" or "K7" in column H to another sheet at the last line. Eventually I will want to delete the copied row.
I have't tried to implement the lastrow nor the delete row wet but right now I'm stock just to get the copy to work with the filter condition.
If i take out the "for" loop the copy work.

```
function copyrange() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var destsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feuille2"); //destination sheet >where to copy the source
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 11); //source to copy
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //variable for the filter

for (n=0; n<data.length; ++n) {
    if (data[n] == "AAF" || "SEQ" || "K7")
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(destsheet.getRange(1, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Java have to do with this?

Comment: Is this java or javascript you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, Javascript. Working with Google sheet and script editor inside it.

Comment: Thanks anyway but I fanaly found a code that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a code that work for me.

```
function Validation() {
          var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Needed');
          var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Acquired');

          var data = sheet1.getRange(1,1, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

          var dest = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
Logger.log(data[i][7]);// just to check if the condition is true sometimes ;-)
            if (data[i][7] == "AAF" || data[i][7] == "SEQ" || data[i][7] == "K7"){ 
              dest.push(data[i]); 
            }
          } // here is the end of the for loop
        Logger.log(dest) ; // log the dest array instead
            if (dest.length > 0 ) { // if something has been written in your array then batch write it to the dest. sheet
            sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,dest.length,dest[0].length).setValues(dest);
            }
        }
```