# Script for condition based copy cells from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write a simple script to copy cells from "source" spreadsheet `C5:K5`  and paste it in "target" sheet in appropriate row based on value in `B5`. I could not able to find the exact scripting code. Next I attached sample spreadsheet which helps to describe what I am looking for:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PoeIbmO1VTYYR9jViw6rHV0Pnzg357AkZJIA28My2LA/edit?usp=sharing

The following script is what I have tried, it is running fine, but it is not pasting the copied values in appropriate row. For example, if I run the script in shared spreadsheet "sample", values are pasted in row number - 101. But it should be pasted in row number - 55.

```
function create() {
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
    var dest;

    var range1 = sheet1.getRange(5,2);
    var tune = range1.getValue();
    Logger.log('tune is ' + tune);

    if (tune != null){ 
        var copyrange = sheet1.getRange("C5:J5");
    }

    var compare1 = sheet2.getRange("B5:B105");
    var compare = sheet2.getRange("B5:B105").getValues();
    Logger.log('sheet2 values are ' + compare); 
    var i;
    var dest=[];


    for(var j=1; j< compare.length; j++) {

        var find = compare[j];

        // Logger.log("find vlaue is" + find);
        //Logger.log("tune vlaue is" + tune);
        if (find = tune) {
            dest.push(compare[j]);
            //var r= compare.getRow.range();
        }
    }
    Logger.log('J value is' + j);

    copyrange.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 3, 10, j, j);

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but here is not a place for you to ask the work to be done for you. You should try yourself and come here to ask your doubts x)

Comment: Yes. I understood. I tried by using this script.                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631072/copy-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-base-on-cell-value       But I could not able to modify and use it for me.

Comment: After understanding the script basics, I can able to run the script in spread sheet. But the issue is that it is not paste in the correct row.

Comment: Edit your question, add the code you have and describe what's happening. Also add to your question the script you tried to use before describing your actual script. Afterwards comment here to tell me, I don't know `vba`, but I may be able to help you…

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I am writing script for google spreadsheet. I added my spreadsheet script in my question. Please give your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the function [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)):

> copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)
>
> Copy the content of the range to the given location. If the
>   destination is larger or smaller than the source range then the source
>   will be repeated or truncated accordingly.

you need to specify the row and row end as last parameters. You were entering variable `j` which is the sheet1 `"B5:B105"` range when the `for` loop exhausts (the comparison with the `if` was doing nothing). Therefore, `j` takes value `105-5+1=101`. If you want the copy to be placed at line `55`, just change `j` to `55` in the line. But if you want it to be done automatically, you can use the following code:

```
function create() {
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
    var dest;

    var range1 = sheet1.getRange(5,2);
    var tune = range1.getValue();
    Logger.log('tune is ' + tune);

    if (tune != null){ 
        var copyrange = sheet1.getRange("C5:J5");
    }

    var compareRange = sheet2.getRange("B5:B105");
    var compareValues = compareRange.getValues();
    Logger.log('sheet2 values are ' + compareValues); 
    var i;
    var dest=[];


    for(var j=1; j< compareValues.length; j++) {

        // Logger.log("find vlaue is" + find);
        //Logger.log("tune vlaue is" + tune);
        if (compareValues[j] == tune) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Logger.log('J value is' + j);

    var startRow = compareRange.getRow();

    copyrange.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 3, 10, j+startRow, j+startRow);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I understood your code and it is working for me.

Comment: @jsmanian You are welcome. Consider clicking the check at the answer left (near to the voting number) to your question to close the thread x)